# Transition is not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am using following code for animating svg path. This works fine in chrome and firefox. But in IE scaling one happens. Transition is not working. Please find my code

```js
function transform() {
            var scale = "scale(2 2)";
            var path = document.getElementById("scale");
            //path.setAttribute('transform', scale);
            //path.style.transition = "all 2s";
            var style = document.createElement('style');
            style.type = "text/css";
            style.innerHTML = '.two{-webkit-transition: all 5s 0.5s;transition: all 5s 0.5s;} .grow{-webkit-transform: scale(2.0,2.0);}';
            document.body.appendChild(style);
            path.setAttribute('class', 'two grow');
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="transform()">Scale</button>
    <svg width="900" height="600">
        <g transform="translate(110,110)">
            <path d="M0 -43.3 50 43.3 -50 43.3Z" fill=" yellow" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"
                  id="scale" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Any suggestions to achieve this kind of animation in IE10?

Comment: Write it in javascript using setTimeout. IE 10 does not support CSS transforms of SVG.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not have a proper doctype declaration as the very first line in a document, IE will enter compatibility mode and most features will not work as expected. Ensure that you have a valid doctype (!DOCTYPE html will be fine) and add meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"  to your document .

Comment: IE 10 does not support CSS transfoms on SVG elements whether it's in edge mode or backwards compatibility mode.